# How to use the previous command output to use as a part of another command: python

Tags: python, linux, command-line, command, concatenation

I have been trying to use the output of a system command to use it as a part of the command in the next portion. However, I cannot seem to join it up properly and hence not being able to run the second command properly. The OS used is KALI LINUX and python 2.7

```
#IMPORTS
import commands, os, subprocess

os.system('mkdir -p ~/Desktop/TOOLS')
checkdir = commands.getoutput('ls ~/Desktop')

if 'TOOLS' in checkdir:
    currentwd = subprocess.check_output('pwd', shell=True)
    cmd = 'cp -R {}/RAW ~/Desktop/TOOLS/'.format(currentwd)
    os.system(cmd)
    os.system('cd ~/Desktop/TOOLS')
    os.system('pwd')
```

The errors are:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/media/root/ARSENAL’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
sh: 2: /RAW: not found
/media/root/ARSENAL
```

It seems that the reading of the first command is alright but it can't join with the RAW portion. I have read many other solutions, but they seem to be for shell scripting instead.

Comment: Is there some reason you're averse to using Python's `os.mkdir()`, `os.listdir()`, `os.getcwd()` and `shutil.copytree()`?

Comment: @Aya Not really but the the copying part has a folder no? since the RAW folder is in the cwd. I need to join it up somehow. I also cannot use os.listdir as I need to check if the folder TOOLS is created

Comment: @Kode.Error404> Aya's point is, given all file manipulations are easily doable directly in python, trying to invoke external tools to do them is silly. And less performant. And more error-prone. And less portable.

Comment: @Kode.Error404> For instance, you could just `shutil.copytree('./RAW', '/home/some_user/Desktop/TOOLS')` and be done with it.

Comment: @Spectras I did not use/know that function before hence I did not try it

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module documentation then. It's full of functions useful for manipulating files. It's much easier than messing with external tools.

Comment: @Kode.Error404 See also updated answer.

Comment: @Aya This error appears even when I have clearly deleted the folder `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install2.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(SOURCE_PATH, DEST_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 177, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/root/Desktop/TOOLS'`

Comment: Seems `shutil.copytree()` does more than I was expecting. See updated answer.

Comment: @Aya It's great. There's a slight error. Its `os.getcwd()` not os.pwd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you haven't called `os.chdir()` anywhere prior to the `cp -R`, then you can use a relative path. Changing the code to...

```
if 'TOOLS' in checkdir:
    cmd = 'cp -R RAW ~/Desktop/TOOLS'
    os.system(cmd)
```

...should do the trick.

Note that the line...

```
os.system('cd ~/Desktop/TOOLS')
```

...will not do what you expect. `os.system()` spawns a subshell, so it will just change the working directory for that process and then exit. The calling process's working directory will remain unchanged.

If you want to change the working directory for the calling process, use...

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/TOOLS'))
```

---

However, Python has all this functionality built-in, so you can do it without spawning any subshells...

```
import os, shutil


# Specify your path constants once only, so it's easier to change
# them later
SOURCE_PATH = 'RAW'
DEST_PATH = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/TOOLS/RAW')

# Recursively copy the files, creating the destination path if necessary.
shutil.copytree(SOURCE_PATH, DEST_PATH)

# Change to the new directory
os.chdir(DEST_PATH)

# Print the current working directory
print os.getcwd()
```

Comment: The code is working fine with your answer. Even though everything is working now, there is this error though. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.chdir('~/Desktop/TOOLS')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/TOOLS'

Comment: …because there is no directory named `~`.

Comment: Do i have to specify it as /root? Even though its the same?

Comment: What do you mean it is the same? `/root` is not the same as `~`. Try `touch '~'` in your shell, you'll see it creates a file named `~`.

Comment: @spectras Oh thanks for the reminder. That slipped off my mind.

Comment: @Kode.Error404> If you meant to expand ~ as an alias for user's home directory as per the commonly used convention, you may do so with `os.path.expanduser(path)`.

Comment: @spectras Good point. I forgot that was expanded by the shell.

Comment: That was what I was looking for but I was not sure of the terminology.